# Link CSS file from React index.html to Flask backend

Tags: css, reactjs, flask

I am trying to link CSS template for some static backend content being served with Flask to my React frontend.

This is my structure:

```
client/
      src/
         components/
                   menu.jsx
      public/
            index.html
web/
   project/
          api/
             routes/
                   templates/
                            menu.html
                            loading.html
                   static/
                         css/
                            bootstrap.css
                            mug.css
```

---

On my first attempt, I've tried to link static content like so:

**index.html**

```
DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/mug.css')}}">    
    <title>My App</title>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="root">
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

The above did not work.

---

I know that if I bring all CSS into 'client/public', `bootstrap.css` will work, but `mug.css` won't, because it is supposed to be rendered dynamically, when 'menu.jsx' renders my backend template as a whole, via 'dangerouslysetHTML', like so:

**menu.jsx**

```
render(){
    var menu_html = this.state.menu_template;
    var menu_template = { __html: menu_html };
    return (
        <div id="parent">
            <h1 className="title is-1"><font color="#C86428">Menu</font></h1>
            <hr/><br/>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={menu_template}/>
        </div>
    );       
}
```

and so:

**menus.html**

```
<a href="{{ url_for('loading') }}</a>
```

and so:

**loading.html**

```
<div class="cup">
  <div class="coffee"></div>
</div>
<div class="smoke"></div>
<p class="txt">Brewing...<br><small></small></p>
```

finally:

**mug.css**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:100,400);

body {
  background:rgb(223,189,150);
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
}

.cup {
  width:76px;
  height:76px;
  background:#dedede;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-38px;
  top:100px;
  box-shadow:-4px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.cup:after{
  content:"";
  width:66px;
  height:66px;
  position:absolute;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:linear-gradient(-45deg, #cbcbcb, #f2f2f2 );
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-33px;
  top:5px;
}

.coffee{
  width:47px;
  height:47px;
  background:#613317;
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(15deg, transparent 0px, transparent 29px, rgba(255,255,255,0.05) 29px, rgba(255,255,255,0.05) 47px);*/
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-25px;
  z-index:1;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-26px;
  border:3px solid #e9e9e9;
  box-shadow:-3px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  transform:rotate(30deg);
  transition:transform 0.3s;
}

.coffee:after{ /*assa*/
 content:"";
  width:15px;
  height:8px;
  position:absolute;
  left:-19px;
  top:18px;
  background:linear-gradient(90deg, #d6d6d6, #aeaeae);
  box-shadow:0px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.coffee:before {
  content:"";
  width:47px;
  height:47px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 95%), radial-gradient(5% 9%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.1), transparent 5%), radial-gradient(0% 0%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.3), transparent 55%);
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 95%), -webkit-radial-gradient(5% 9%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.1), transparent 5%), -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 0%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.3), transparent 55%);
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 95%), -moz-radial-gradient(5% 9%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.1), transparent 5%), -moz-radial-gradient(0% 0%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.3), transparent 55%);
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  border-radius:50%;
}
.cup:hover .coffee {
  transform:rotate(15deg);
}

.smoke {
  width:70px;
  height:100px; 
  background:;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-40px;
  top:43px;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 25%), -webkit-radial-gradient(25% 70%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%), -webkit-radial-gradient(35% 61%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 10%), -webkit-radial-gradient(55% 35%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%);
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 25%), -moz-radial-gradient(25% 70%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%), -moz-radial-gradient(35% 61%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 10%), -moz-radial-gradient(55% 35%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%);
  background-image: radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 25%), radial-gradient(25% 70%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%), radial-gradient(35% 61%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 10%), radial-gradient(55% 35%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%);
  animation:bk 11s infinite ;
}

.smoke:after {
  content:"";
  width:100px;
  height:100px; 
  background:;
  position:absolute;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 25%), -webkit-radial-gradient(25% 70%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%), -webkit-radial-gradient(35% 61%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 10%);
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 25%), -moz-radial-gradient(25% 70%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%), -moz-radial-gradient(35% 61%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 10%);
  background-image: radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 25%), radial-gradient(25% 70%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%), radial-gradient(35% 61%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 10%);
  animation:bk 2s 1s infinite;
}


@keyframes bk {
  0%{ background-position:0 0; opacity:0; }
  15%, 85% { opacity:1;}
  100%{ background-position:-20px -25px, -5px -25px, 0px -25px, 0px -25px; opacity:0;}
}

.txt{
  position:absolute;
  top:184px;
  width:150px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-75px;
}

.txt a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#613317;
}

.txt a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

QUESTION:

So, how do I link this backend CSS to my frontend index.html, or how do I apply it otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know (more like I don't think) there is a way of linking Flask directly with react using the normal Jinja Templating. You will have to work with two totally separate systems if you are to use a front-end framework like ReactJS.

The best way to handle this is usually through using APIs.

Create the backend with API endpoints being produced. This can be done through [Flask Restful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The API endpoints will basically produce data in JSON format.

The API endpoints can be consumed by the front-end React JS. I do not have a link for that but there are plenty of resources online I am sure.

Now, if you need to change particular CSS items on the ReactJS side, you can send particular flags that indicate what you need to change and you can work on the logic. For example, you can produce an endpoint from your backend with the following fields:

```
{
    "user-team": "blue" 
}
```

On the ReactJS the logic can be made to check for this particular field and change the color of a specific element based on it.

Comment: I am doing this as an API already. and I get each template via axios GET request from menu.html, for instance, from endpoint `/menu`. do you need any further edit specifying this?